# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception (Shared preference and gradle wrapper properties)

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle, sharedpreferences, release

I am getting this error when i run the flutter run --release command on terminal. Kindly help me in solving this problem and let me know where i am doing wrong to make its release build successfully.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-0.0.1+2\android\build.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'shared_preferences_macos'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\s
hared_preferences_macos-0.0.1+2\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s


The plugin shared_preferences_macos could not be built due to the issue above.
```

This is my flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

I also updated my gradle wrapper properties to this one but got the same issue

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Open the android folder of the flutter project into the android studio and fix the errors. Once all the errors are fixed then try to create the build and then its definitely working fine.

Comment: After doing that, i am still facing the same issue.

Comment: have you checked this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25116
was facing the same Gradle related issue(on PC) so I just deleted Gradle folders and ran the project again after InvalidatingChache/Restart. It took a while to download Gradle but the issue got resolved.

Comment: my problem got solved by updating the gradle version number in all respective files.

Comment: Hello @Umair

I'm facing the same issue. Can you please explain to me regarding the Gradle version changes you have did on all the respective file?

Comment: Same problem here, can you explain better how to solve that?

Comment: I update my version number manually, by going to respective files the location of files that have error was already showing you in terminal. and after opening the files in notepad just change the gradle version. You have to change the version number only solved the problem

Comment: @JoãoArmando
Check my answer. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @umair for the solution. Let me give a brief understanding of solution.

We have to update the version in gradle-wrapper.properties file of respective plugins where an error is showing.

Let's say if error is showing for **"shared_preferences_macos"** then we have to update **version number in gradle-wrapper.properties** file of **"shared_preferences_macos"** plugin from below path.

**PATH:** */Users/admin/Library/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_macos-0.0.1+3/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*

From the above path we have to **open gradle-wrapper.properties** file and have to **update version to 5.4.1 from 4.10.2** in **distributionUrl** variable and save the file. That's it.

**Note:**

- A path for gradle-wrapper.properties file of the respective plugin will be shown on your terminal error message
- Suggested Gradle version will also be shown on your terminal error message
- Repeat the same process for all the plugins where you were facing an error message.

Comment: That works but I should not need to update plugins by hand, if pub downloads a new version it will override those changes. I put out a PR I believe fix this problem: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/2470